# JSF2, i18n and SEO

Tags: jsf, internationalization, seo, jsf-2

I am migrating an application from Struts2 to JSF2. In struts2 I had mapped most of the actions so that the same action returned different locale content depending on the URL. For example:

http://site.com/en/content.action 
http://site.com/es/content.action

The action returned the same JSP which showed spanish or english depending on the URL. With this approach I have "SEO" bookmarkable localized URLs.

Is there any approach for doing this with JSF2? If not, which is the recommended approach for making the same JSF (xhtml) show different locale content depending on a request parameter (?locale=en for example) 
I have solved it using a changeLocale method in a managed bean, which works OK, but as it uses Post, the pages are not SEO as cannot be crawled.

Thanks for any ideas/approach. 
Ignacio

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to look at **[PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/)**

> Any business knows how important Search Engine Optimization can be for sales. PrettyFaces allows SEO-friendly URLs, and improved customer experience. Give your site a uniform, well understood feeling, from the address bar to the buy button.

I have personally used this in one of my app.

in your case if i understood it correctly you can make something like

```
yourdomain.com/en/login
```

Comment: OK, thanks for your reply. I'm using pretty faces and it's very easy to map the /en URls but, is there any recommended approach or best practice to "set" the locale in the request/session based on that "/en/" part in the URL? Translating it into a request parameter as PrettyFaces does automatic needs a filter or Phase listener to search that parameter and change the locale subsequently...